# match a Prop? or any other way to define "Double-negation translation"

Tags: coq

I am trying to define the [Double-negation translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation) for all propositions in Coq, so I can prove the classic facts which are not provable (or have a very hard proof) in "Intuitionistic Logic", but I think this is not possible using `Inductive` or `Fixpoint` keywords. with `Fixpoint`, I need to match an arbitary proposition. (Although I only need first-order logic i.e., conjunction, disjunction, condition, neggation and `forall` and `exists` quantifiers) Also I cannot use `Inductive`. this is my failed approach

```
Inductive NN (P : Prop) : Prop :=
  | nn_cond (P1 P2 : Prop) (Heq : P = P1 /\ P2) (H : NN P1 -> NN P2).
```

I need to prove a `Lemma` similar to this at last

```
Lemma NN__EM (P : Prop) : NN P <-> (excluded_middle -> P).
```

Any Idea for how can I define such a definition?

Comment: I don't think you can do a translation internally. You can prove the double negation of classical facts by hand.

Comment: The problem is just double negation won't work with first-order logic.

Comment: I see no other way than to encode propositions. Maybe using metacoq to write a plugin doing the translation for you.

Comment: Oh, so it's not that simple! thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double-negation translation involves three logical systems. There's a classical logic and an intuitionistic logic, but the translation is not a part of either of these logics. After all, the translation is a relationship between two different universes of logic; how can it belong to one of them? Instead, these logics need to be constructed as objects *inside* some other logic (probably one you "believe" in, or is "real"), and then double-negation translation is a theorem of that ambient logic that describes the two inner logics. TL;DR: Double-negation translation is a process/theorem *about* logic, not *within* logic.

For this reason, you cannot write double-negation translation as such as a lemma within the logic of Coq. I mean, you could certainly define

```
Inductive sentence : Set := ... . (* E.g. syntax of FOL *)
Definition NN : sentence -> sentence.
Definition classically_provable : sentence -> Prop.
Definition intuitionistically_provable : sentence -> Prop.
Theorem double_negation_translation (p : sentence) :
   classically_provable p <-> intuitionistically_provable (NN p).
```

but this does not prove anything about *Coq*. It only proves something about some other logics constructed *inside* Coq. If you wanted to prove this about Coq, you'd have to do that proof in some "higher" system of logic, which is usually either the informal, natural-language logic I'm using right now, or the language Ltac, the tactic language. Ltac programs are the programs that Coq runs to generate proofs. In particular, you could write two tactics. One, if you give it a term `excluded_middle -> P` (aka a classical proof of `P`), will essentially try to root out all the uses of that classicality to produce a new, intuitionistic proof of the double-negation translation of `P`. The other, given an (intuitionistic) proof of the double-negation translation `P`, turns it into a classical proof of `P` (aka it proves `excluded_middle -> P`). (Note my careful language: I say `P` but not `NN P`, only "the double-negation translation of `P`". That's because, *outside* of Coq, in natural language or Ltac, we can define what "the double-negation translation of `P`" is. *Within* Coq, there is no definable `NN : Prop -> Prop` for that.)

So, e.g., you can define the translation of propositions like this:

```
Ltac nn_transl P :=
  lazymatch P with
  | ?L /\ ?R =>
    let L' := nn_transl L in
    let R' := nn_transl R in
    uconstr:(L' /\ R')
  | ?L \/ ?R =>
    let L' := nn_transl L in
    let R' := nn_transl R in
    uconstr:(~(~L' /\ ~R'))
  | not ?Q =>
    let Q' := nn_transl Q in
    uconstr:(~Q')
  | ?L -> ?R =>
    let L' := nn_transl L in
    let R' := nn_transl R in
    uconstr:(L' -> R')
  | forall t: ?T, @?Q t =>
    constr:(
      forall t: T,
      ltac:(
        let Qt := eval hnf in (Q t) in
        let Qt' := nn_transl Qt in
        exact Qt'))
  | exists t: ?T, @?Q t =>
    constr:(
      ~forall t: T,
      ~ltac:(
        let Qt := eval hnf in (Q t) in
        let Qt' := nn_transl Qt in
        exact Qt'))
  | _ => uconstr:(~~P)
  end.
```

Implementing the actual translation of proofs does not seem as easy, but it should be doable. I've implemented the easier direction (double negation to classical):

```
Definition excluded_middle : Prop := forall x, x \/ ~x.

Tactic Notation "assert" "double" "negative" constr(P) "as" ident(H) :=
  let P' := nn_transl P in
  assert (H : P').


Ltac int_to_nn_class_gen' nn_int_to_class_gen P :=
  let x := fresh "x" in
  let excl := fresh "excl" in
  lazymatch P with
  | ?L /\ ?R =>
    let xl := fresh x "_l" in
    let xr := fresh x "_r" in
    let rec_L := int_to_nn_class_gen' nn_int_to_class_gen L in
    let rec_R := int_to_nn_class_gen' nn_int_to_class_gen R in
    uconstr:(
      fun (x : P) (excl : excluded_middle) =>
      let (xl, xr) := x in
      conj (rec_L xl excl) (rec_R xr excl))
  | ?L \/ ?R =>
    let L' := nn_transl L in
    let R' := nn_transl R in
    let arg := fresh x "_arg" in
    let arg_l := fresh arg "_l" in
    let arg_r := fresh arg "_r" in
    let rec_L := int_to_nn_class_gen' nn_int_to_class_gen L in
    let rec_R := int_to_nn_class_gen' nn_int_to_class_gen R in
    uconstr:(
      fun (x : P) (excl : excluded_middle) (arg : ~L' /\ ~R') =>
      let (arg_l, arg_r) := arg in
      match x with
      | or_introl x => arg (rec_L x excl)
      | or_intror x => arg (rec_R x excl)
      end)
  | not ?Q =>
    let Q' := nn_transl Q in
    let arg := fresh x "_arg" in
    let rec_Q := nn_int_to_class_gen Q in
    uconstr:(
      fun (x : P) (excl : excluded_middle) (arg : Q') => x (rec_Q arg excl))
  | ?L -> ?R =>
    let L' := nn_transl L in
    let arg := fresh x "_arg" in
    let rec_L := nn_int_to_class_gen L in
    let rec_R := int_to_nn_class_gen' nn_int_to_class_gen R in
    uconstr:(
      fun (x : P) (excl : excluded_middle) (arg : L') =>
      rec_R (x (rec_L arg excl)) excl)
  | forall t: ?T, @?Q t =>
    constr:(
      fun (x : P) (excl : excluded_middle) (t : T) =>
      ltac:(
        let Qt := eval hnf in (Q t) in
        let rec_Qt := int_to_nn_class_gen' nn_int_to_class_gen Qt in
        exact (rec_Qt (x t) excl)))
  | exists t: ?T, @?Q t =>
    let arg := fresh x "_arg" in
    let wit := fresh x "_wit" in
    constr:(
      fun
        (x : P) (excl : excluded_middle)
        (arg :
          forall t: T,
          ltac:(
            let Qt := eval hnf in (Q t) in
            let Qt' := nn_transl Qt in
            exact (~Qt'))) =>
      match x with ex_intro _ t wit =>
        ltac:(
          let Qt := eval hnf in (Q t) in
          let rec_Qt := int_to_nn_class_gen' nn_int_to_class_gen Qt in
          exact (arg t (rec_Qt wit excl)))
      end)
  | _ =>
    let arg := fresh x "_arg" in
    uconstr:(fun (x : P) (excl : excluded_middle) (arg : ~P) => arg x)
  end.

Ltac nn_int_to_class_gen' int_to_nn_class_gen P :=
  let NNP := nn_transl P in
  let nnx := fresh "nnx" in
  let excl := fresh "excl" in
  lazymatch P with
  | ?L /\ ?R =>
    let nnl := fresh nnx "_l" in
    let nnr := fresh nnx "_r" in
    let rec_L := nn_int_to_class_gen' int_to_nn_class_gen L in
    let rec_R := nn_int_to_class_gen' int_to_nn_class_gen R in
    uconstr:(
      fun (nnx : NNP) (excl : excluded_middle) =>
      let (nnl, nnr) := nnx in
      conj (rec_L nnl excl) (rec_R nnr excl))
  | ?L \/ ?R =>
    let L' := nn_transl L in
    let R' := nn_transl R in
    let prf := fresh nnx "_prf" in
    let arg := fresh nnx "_arg" in
    let arg_l := fresh arg "_l" in
    let arg_r := fresh arg "_r" in
    let rec_L := nn_int_to_class_gen' int_to_nn_class_gen L in
    let rec_R := nn_int_to_class_gen' int_to_nn_class_gen R in
    uconstr:(
      fun (nnx : NNP) (excl : excluded_middle) =>
      match excl P with
      | or_introl prf => prf
      | or_intror prf =>
        nnx (conj
          (fun arg : L' => prf (or_introl (rec_L arg)))
          (fun arg : R' => prf (or_intror (rec_R arg))))
      end)
  | not ?Q =>
    let arg := fresh nnx "_arg" in
    let rec_Q := int_to_nn_class_gen Q in
    uconstr:(
      fun (nnx : NNP) (excl : excluded_middle) (arg : Q) =>
      nnx (rec_Q arg excl))
  | ?L -> ?R =>
    let arg := fresh nnx "_arg" in
    let rec_L := int_to_nn_class_gen L in
    let rec_R := nn_int_to_class_gen' int_to_nn_class_gen R in
    uconstr:(
      fun (nnx : NNP) (excl : excluded_middle) (arg : L) =>
      rec_R (nnx (rec_L arg excl)) excl)
  | forall t: ?T, @?Q t =>
    constr:(
      fun (nnx : NNP) (excl : excluded_middle) (t : T) =>
      ltac:(
        let Qt := eval hnf in (Q t) in
        let rec_Qt := nn_int_to_class_gen' int_to_nn_class_gen Qt in
        exact (rec_Qt (nnx t) excl)))
  | exists t: ?T, @?Q t =>
    let prf := fresh nnx "_prf" in
    let wit := fresh nnx "_wit" in
    constr:(
      fun (nnx : NNP) (excl : excluded_middle) =>
      match excl P with
      | or_introl prf => prf
      | or_intror prf =>
        False_ind P
        ( nnx
          ( fun
              (t : T)
              (wit :
                ltac:(
                  let Qt := eval hnf in (Q t) in
                  let Q' := nn_transl Qt in
                  exact Q')) =>
            ltac:(
              let Qt := eval hnf in (Q t) in
              let rec_Qt := nn_int_to_class_gen' int_to_nn_class_gen Qt in
              exact (prf (ex_intro _ t (rec_Qt wit excl))))))
      end)
  | _ =>
    let prf := fresh nnx "_prf" in
    uconstr:(
      fun (nnx : NNP) (excl : excluded_middle) =>
      match excl P with
      | or_introl prf => prf
      | or_intror prf => False_ind P (nnx prf)
      end)
  end.

Ltac int_to_nn_class_gen :=
  let rec
    int_to_nn_class_gen :=
      fun P => int_to_nn_class_gen' nn_int_to_class_gen P
  with
    nn_int_to_class_gen :=
      fun P => nn_int_to_class_gen' int_to_nn_class_gen P
  in
  int_to_nn_class_gen.
Ltac nn_int_to_class_gen :=
  let rec
    int_to_nn_class_gen :=
      fun P => int_to_nn_class_gen' nn_int_to_class_gen P
  with
    nn_int_to_class_gen :=
      fun P => nn_int_to_class_gen' int_to_nn_class_gen P
  in
  nn_int_to_class_gen.

Tactic Notation "nn_int_to_class" constr(P) hyp(H) :=
  let new := fresh "class_" H in
  let transl := nn_int_to_class_gen P in
  refine (let new : excluded_middle -> P := transl H in _).
```

Looking back at this, I think you might be able to implement this direction with `Class`es and `Instance`s (type-directed lookup of implicit values is another Coq process that is outside the logic of Coq), since the translation is done entirely by a self-contained term, but I'm not sure the other direction (which would be analyzing the actual proof term `fun (excl : excluded_middle) => ...` for uses of `excl`) can be done this way. Here's a proof of the Drinker's Paradox:

```
Theorem nn_excluded_middle X : ~~(X \/ ~X).
Proof. tauto. Defined.

Theorem drinker's (P : Set) (x : P) (D : P -> Prop)
                : excluded_middle -> exists y, D y -> forall z, D z.
Proof.
  assert double negative (exists y, D y -> forall z, D z) as prf.
  {
    intros no.
    apply (nn_excluded_middle (forall y, D y)).
    intros [everyone | someone].
    - apply no with x.
      intros prf_x y prf_y.
      apply prf_y, everyone.
    - apply (nn_excluded_middle (exists y, ~D y)).
      intros [[y sober] | drunk].
      + apply no with y.
        intros drunk.
        contradiction (drunk sober).
      + contradict someone.
        intros y.
        specialize (no y).
        contradict no.
        intros drunk_y z sober_z.
        apply drunk.
        exists z.
        exact sober_z.
  }
  nn_int_to_class (exists y, D y -> forall z, D z) prf.
  exact class_prf.
Defined.
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your great answer. I thought there might be some tricky ways, but as you properly described it is not possible in the same level with Coq to talk about Coq. But I was looking for a way to go one step higher as you could introduce the language Ltac, this is great.

Comment: Also I assume you meant `classically_provable` and `intuitionistically_provable` are of type `sentence -> Prop`, not important but this answer is great so I just mean editing that makes it perfect.